# Populating data on radiobuttonlist based on data selected in dropdownlist

Tags: sql, drop-down-menu, radiobuttonlist, populate

I have been having issues with the following problem the past 2 days.

I wish to create a poll where a user will choose a poll from a drop down list. Upon selection, the selected poll will fetch data from the database based on its ID and fill a radio button list with 3 options: Date 1, Date 2, Date 3.

I have a database table storing ID, expiry data, date 1, date 2, date 3 of a poll created.

I am able to generate the drop down list of polls created, however i am unable to make the selected poll respond when selected to fill the radi button list with the different date options. The following are snippets of my code which i have written:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        fillPollOptions();

        if(pollDropDownList.SelectedIndex > 0){
            MultiView1.Visible = true;
            btnListPollOptions.Visible = true;
            pollDateCreated();
        }
    }

    public void fillPollOptions()
    {
        pollDropDownList.Items.Clear();

        string selectSQL = "SELECT id, dateExpired FROM tblPolls";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
        SqlDataReader reader;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
                newItem.Text = reader["id"].ToString();
                newItem.Value = reader["dateExpired"].ToString();
                pollDropDownList.Items.Add(newItem);
            }
            reader.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            lblListError.Text = "Error reading list of names. ";
            lblListError.Text += err.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    public void pollDateCreated()
    {

        string selectSQL = "SELECT dateExpired, dateCreated FROM tblPolls";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
        SqlDataReader reader;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            lblQuestionDateCreated.Text = reader["dateCreated"].ToString();
            lblQuestionDateExpires.Text = reader["dateExpired"].ToString();
            reader.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            lblListError.Text = "Error reading list of names. ";
            lblListError.Text += err.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    protected void btnPollList()
    {
        string selectSQL; 
        selectSQL = "SELECT firstDate,secondDate,thirdDate FROM tblPolls ";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
        SqlDataReader reader;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();

            btnListPollOptions.DataSource = reader;
            btnListPollOptions.DataBind();

            reader.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            lblMessage.Text = "Error displaying poll";
        }

    }
```

I am unsure if there needs to be any data source binding on the front end. My .asp codes are:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="pollDropDownList" runat="server" Height="16px" 
    Width="132px" >
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="btnListPollOptions" runat="server" 
        DataTextField="firstDate, secondDate, thirdDate" DataValueField="id">
        <asp:ListItem>Not Available</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I will really appreciate it if any help can be offered!!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change your selectSQL = "SELECT firstDate,secondDate,thirdDate FROM tblPolls "; query to selectSQL = "SELECT firstDate opdate FROM tblPolls union all
SELECT secondDate FROM tblPolls union all
SELECT thirdDate FROM tblPolls" 
and change this DataTextField="firstDate, secondDate, thirdDate" DataValueField="id" to
DataTextField="opdate" DataValueField="opdate"

I think there will be some where condition for above slectSQL. Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am still unable to bind the radio list buttons with my database. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Now what problem you are facing ? Can you mention errors or behaviou you found after above implementation